Flutter InAppWebview is not able to detect route changes of a web application
Flutter InAppWebview is not able to detect route changes of a web application which is using useNavigate of react-router-dom.
I tried this but was not able to detect webpage route changes.
The library used for routing in the React webapp is useNavigate() but it's not able to read route changes on Flutter InAppWebview.
The Flutter plugin being used is flutter_inappwebview.
   InAppWebView(
                initialSettings: initalSetting.value,
                initialUrlRequest:
                    URLRequest(url: WebUri(viewModel.prefillData!.bookingUrl)),
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                  webviewController.value = controller;
                },
                onReceivedError: (controller, request, error) {
                  Logger.log.severe(error);
                },
                onCloseWindow: (controller) {
                  context.pop();
                },
                onCreateWindow: (controller, createWindowAction) async {
                  await Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => InAppWebViewWindow(
                        windowId: createWindowAction.windowId,
                        windowRequest: createWindowAction.request,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );

                  return Future.value(true);
                },
                onNavigationResponse: (controller, navigationResponse) async {
                  Logger.log.info('onConsoleMessage: $navigationResponse ');
                },
                onReceivedHttpError:
                    (controller, request, errorResponse) async {
                  AnalyticsManager.triggerEvent(
                    event: EventName.fincareErrorDebugLog,
                    filterAnalytics: [
                      AvailableAnalytics.firebaseAnalytics,
                      AvailableAnalytics.moengage,
                    ],
                    properties: {
                      'statusCode': errorResponse.statusCode,
                      'url': request.url.toString(),
                    },
                  );
                },
                onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                  currentWebviewUri.value = url;
                },
                onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                  AnalyticsManager.triggerEvent(
                    event: EventName.fincareDebugLog,
                    filterAnalytics: [
                      AvailableAnalytics.firebaseAnalytics,
                      AvailableAnalytics.moengage,
                    ],
                    properties: {
                      EventProps.link: url.toString(),
                    },
                  );

                  var initialUrl = WebUri(
                    '${FlavorConfig.instance.values.ujjivanBaseUrl}apply',
                  );

                  await controller.injectCSSCode(
                    source:
                        '.navbar {visibility: hidden;display: none;} .TC {visibility:hidden;display: none;}',
                  );

                  if (!((url?.host == initialUrl.host) &&
                      (url?.path == initialUrl.path))) {
                    errorShown.value = true;
                  }
                },
              
                onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                  pageProgress.value = progress;
                },
                onGeolocationPermissionsHidePrompt: (controller) {},
                onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                  Logger.log.severe(consoleMessage);
                },
                shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
                  var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;
                  return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                },
              ),


I had a similar problem and solved it with reload in webview:
 controller.reload()); 

inside onLoadStop()
